# dblink does not exist even when the extension already exists?

Tags: postgresql, insert, dblink

So I'm new to using `dblink`, I just created a script that inserts data into a table from another database. I received the error `function dblink(unknown,unknown) does not exist`.

So I checked online, and used `CREATE EXTENSION dblink`, ended up getting this message `extension "dblink" already exists`.

My dblink code is like this:

```
INSERT INTO tableA
 SELECT tbl.colA,tbl.colB,...
 FROM dblink('dbname=anotherDB', 'SELECT colA,colB,...
                 FROM tableB')
as tbl(colA,colB,...)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out in which schema the extension is installed. In my case this schema is `ext`:

```
select nspname as schema
from pg_extension e
join pg_namespace n on n.oid = e.extnamespace
where extname = 'dblink'

 schema 
--------
 ext
(1 row)
```

Add the schema name to the search path, e.g.:

```
set search_path to public, ext;
```

or use the qualified name of the function `dblink()`, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO tableA
 SELECT tbl.colA,tbl.colB,...
 FROM ext.dblink('dbname=anotherDB', 'SELECT colA,colB,...
                 FROM tableB')
as tbl(colA,colB,...)
```

Comment: it was the schema, had to change it from public to my schema