# ERROR: function dblink(unknown, unknown) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I have defined a foreign server pointing to another database. I then want to execute a function in that database and get back the results.

When I try this:

```
SELECT * FROM  dblink('mylink','select someschema.somefunction(''test'', ''ABC'')')
```

or this:

```
SELECT t.n FROM  dblink('mylink', 'select * from someschema.mytable') as t(n text)
```

I get the error:

> ERROR: function dblink(unknown, unknown) does not exist

Running as superuser.

Comment: ```create extension dblink;```

Comment: Thanks, I have done that as part of db setup. And this error still happens.

Comment: ran on same db?..

Comment: select * from pg_available_extensions shows it.

Comment: yes it is same db

Comment: The problem was that dblink was not created in public schema as expected. so have to  qualify with someschema.dblink(...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dblink does not exist even when the extension already exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46557439/dblink-does-not-exist-even-when-the-extension-already-exists)

Answer (score 55):

You need to install an extension dblink

```
create extension dblink;
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case (as reported also in @HuFlungPu comments) the problem was that I initially created the `dblink` in `public` schema. I executed a `SET search_path TO my_schema` because I was working on `my_schema`; so when querying the dblink I was receiving

```
ERROR: function dblink(unknown, unknown) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

After executing a `SET search_path TO public` (where 'public' is the schema in which the dblink was created) I was able to query again successfully through the dblink

Comment: and in my case it was not even "public". So thank you!

Comment: how to install  "create extension dblink" by using python code? please suggest.

Comment: @Hushen dblink is a function available in Postgres, I don't know what exactly you mean by "installing using python code"

Answer (score 6):

In my case the problem was that I was using a different user than the one I used to create the extension.

I solved it using the same user that ran the
***create extension dblink;***
command