# How use dblink function of postgres in Laravel query

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Now I have a problem when use `dblink` postgres in Laravel query

My query in postgres like that

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM dblink('host=localhost user=postgres password=123@123a dbname=shbbank',
'SELECT contract_ref_no,currency_iso,report_date FROM bigq.credit_data') 
AS source(contract_ref_no text,currency_iso text,report_date date)"
```

And then I do that query in Laravel

```
DB::select($query);
```

I got error:

> Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  function dblink(unknown, unknown) does
>   not exist. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Please help me to resolve

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50936251/error-function-dblinkunknown-unknown-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

It seems that extension `dblink` has not been created.

Try running script `create extension dblink` via migration or directly on your database. Once you have created the extension, you can use `dblink` from the right schema.

Comment: I have run that script on postgres (PG admin) be OK. But It not working in Laravel query